# StickyScroll inside multiple jQueryUI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Im trying to let a div element inside jQueryUI Tab scroll in one tab it works but when i have multiple tabs it gains a big offset or won't scroll anymore.

http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/
This is the plugin i use to keep the div inside my screen and inside the tabcontent while scrolling.

Anyone can confirm this problem or know another plugin that works better inside UI tabs?